# Correct way of using RxJS

Tags: angular, rxjs6

I have this method in Angular (latest, package.json shows 7.0.0) and `Rxjs 6.3.3`. I am calling a **SpringBoot** Rest API that returns a list of Flights. I want to convert into `Observable<Flight[]>`.

```
search(searchquery): Observable<Flight[]>
  {
    return this.http.post('/searchservice/search/get', searchquery)
      .pipe(map(response => 
      {
        return (response.map((flight: Flight) =>
        {
          return new Flight().deserialize(flight);
        }));
      }));

  }
```

But when building, I get this error

> "error TS2339: Property 'map' does not exist on type 'Object'"

. The error is shown in the `response.map((flight: Flight) =>` code. May I know what I am doing wrong?
Based on the query below, this is the json response printed.

```
0: {id: 4, flightNumber: "BF101", origin: "NYC", destination: "SFO", flightDate: "22-JAN-16", …}
1: {id: 7, flightNumber: "BF105", origin: "NYC", destination: "SFO", flightDate: "22-JAN-16", …}
2: {id: 10, flightNumber: "BF106", origin: "NYC", destination: "SFO", flightDate: "22-JAN-16", ..}
```

And one more thing. The code worked perfectly yesterday, but today morning, it started showing errors. Weird!!!
What I am trying to do is similar to this code below which is written in the book, The complete book on Angular.

```
return this.http.get(queryUrl)
  .map((response: Response) => {
   return (<any>response.json()).items.map(item => {
   SearchResult({
      id: item.id.videoId,
      title: item.snippet.title,
      description: item.snippet.description,
      thumbnailUrl: item.snippet.thumbnails.high.url
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Your response is an object. You need an array to in order to use the `response.map`

Comment: The response is a json array and isn't the response reactive? I can simply assign to an Object but I want to convert into a TypeScript type.

Comment: could you please post sample of your ajax answer ?

Comment: Depends what are you returning from server. Map is funcion of sequence (ex. Array). It seems that you're not returning array or response.data hold your array.

Comment: @KrishnaKumar you can't apply map on { }  , should be an array [].map(). If you can share some part of your json , that would be easy for us to understand the issue

Comment: @KrishnaKumar You seem to be under the mistaken assumption that `response` itself is an observable. That is simply untrue.

Comment: @AluanHaddad I remembered reading it like that somewhere. So I am wrong there..

Comment: @KrishnaKumar Well the key thing is to pay attention to the types. Also make sure you let the types propagate via inference so you do not mislead yourself. I notice that you are specifying the argument types in callback parameter lists. Never, ever do that! If you accidentally produce an array or obs of `any` such annotations silence compiler-errors  and break inference. The parameter type of a call back is flowed from the type of the function that the call back is passed to.

Comment: @AluanHaddad I have posted my solution as an answer. Can you check whether I am doing it right? Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At last, this is the code that worked. Cast the response as `<Flight[]>` and then map it.

```
search(searchquery): Observable<Flight[]>
  {
    return this.http.post('/searchservice/search/get', searchquery)
      .pipe(map(response =>
      {
        return (<Flight[]>response).map(flight => new Flight().deserialize(flight))
      }));

  }
```

Comment: I would like to know the theory of it. response.map doesn't work because it's just an object, but why does (<any>response).map work?

Comment: It works at compile time because of your type assertion `<any>` which disables all type checking, and so the typescript compiler allows any message to be called on the value to which is applied. If response does not have a map method it will fail at one time. Don't use tape instructions to make your code match some example code that is either wrong or taken out of context

Comment: This isn't a good answer anyway because you're just dodging the type system instead of figuring out the shape of your response and writing a type that matches it. That you need that type assertion implies that you are doing it wrong and using the language improperly

Comment: I am no master in Angular or RxJs. I am into Spring stuff and all related to that. This is for Microservices training to show how security can be applied and propagated using Zuul and all. This piece of code is just for that. I will definitely update based on your comments on how to handle type checking the proper way. Any links to how its done is appreciated.

Comment: Changed the `<any>response` to use correct type to `<Flight[]>response`